# How can I override onCurrentListChanged of ListAdapter with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-listadapter

I hope to override `onCurrentListChanged` of ListAdapter, but Code A doesn't work, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
myAdapter.onCurrentListChanged(){previousList,  currentList ->
            
}
```

**Added Content**

To Alexey Romanov: Thanks!

Code C can work well, but Code D by your answer can not work, what error is there?

**Code C**

```
private val myAdapter by lazy{
             VoiceAdapters(mHomeViewModel,mPlay)
           }
```

**Code D**

```
  private val myAdapter by lazy{
            VoiceAdapters(mHomeViewModel,mPlay) {
               override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<MVoice>,  currentList: MutableList<MVoice>) {
                
               }
        }
```

**Both**

```
class VoiceAdapters (private val aHomeViewModel: HomeViewModel, private val mPlay: PlayInterface):
        ListAdapter<MVoice, VoiceAdapters.VoiceViewHolder>(MVoiceDiffCallback()) {

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you show looks more like an attempt to *call* `onCurrentListChanged`, but

1. that would be simply `myAdapter.onCurrentListChanged(someList1, someList2)`;
2. it *probably* shouldn't be called manually.

To *override* a method of `ListAdapter`, you need to do it when defining `myAdapter` (or whatever class it's an instance of). E.g.

```
val myAdapter = object : ListAdapter<SomeType> {
    override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<SomeType>, currentList: MutableList<SomeType>) {
        ...
    }

    // other overrides
}
```

See [object expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) for the explanation and details of `object : ...` syntax.

When you already have `myAdapter`, it's too late, though you could create a new `ListAdapter` which has its own `onCurrentListChanged` and delegates to `myAdapter` for other methods. Kotlin has special support for this pattern for interfaces, but `ListAdapter` is a class and you'd have to do everything manually:

```
val myAdapter2 = object : ListAdapter<SomeType> {
    override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<SomeType>, currentList: MutableList<SomeType>) {
        ...
    }

    override fun getCurrentList() = myAdapter.getCurrentList()

    override fun getItemCount() = myAdapter.getItemCount()

    // etc.
}
```

---

> Code C can work well, but Code D by your answer can not work, what error is there?

It should be

```
private val myAdapter by lazy {
    object : VoiceAdapters(mHomeViewModel,mPlay) {
        override fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: MutableList<MVoice>,  currentList: MutableList<MVoice>) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Thanks! After I set `class VoiceAdapters` as `open class VoiceAdapters`, your code works well.

Comment: Code D is just like your code, why doesn't Code D work ?

Comment: It's simply not legal Kotlin syntax. Are you maybe coming from Java and expecting just to remove `new` as if calling a constructor?